# ¿Por que obtengo SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has not 'tax', en wdsl con complextype anidados?

Tags: php, array, soap

Tengo que consumir un web services SOAP con PHP y obtengo el error del título.

La estructura (parcial) del wsdl es la siguiente

```
<xs:element name="Obligations" type="tns:ObligationsType"/>
<xs:complexType name="ObligationsType">
<xs:sequence>

<xs:element maxOccurs="99" name="Taxes" type="tns:TaxesType"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="TaxesType">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="tax">
<xs:simpleType>
<xs:restriction base="xs:int">
<xs:maxInclusive value="9999"/>
<xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="amount">
<xs:simpleType>
<xs:restriction base="xs:double">
<xs:minInclusive value="0.01"/>
<xs:maxInclusive value="9999999999.99"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

El array asociativo que envío:

```
$params = array(
  'token' => $TOKEN,
  'sign' => $SIGN,
  'paymentEntity' => 1001,
  'form' => array(
      'formNumber' => 6042,
    'idPaymentType' => 951,
    'Obligations' => array (
      array( 
          'Taxes' => array(
          'tax' => 6041,
            'amount' => 602.0 
        )
      )
    )
  )                
);
```

Con Clases

```
class Taxes{
  var $tax;
  var $amount;
}

class Obligations{
  var $Taxes;
}

class form{
  var $formNumber;
  var $idPaymentType;
  var $Obligations;
}
```

Intenté hacerlo con clases y obtengo el mismo error. El problema está desde el objeto Obligations.
Intenté anidando así:

> 'Obligations' =>array ('Taxes' =>array('tax'=> 1,'amount'=> 1.0)) obtengo Unrecognized field Obligations
>
> 'Obligations' =>array ('tax'=> 1,'amount'=> 1.0) obtengo object has no 'Taxes' property
>
> 'Obligations' =>array (array('Taxes' =>array('tax'=> 1,'amount'=> 1.0))) obtengo object has no 'tax' property
>
> 'Obligations' =>array ('Taxes' =>array('tax'=> 1)) obtengo object has no 'amount' property
>
> 'Obligations' =>array ('Taxes' =>array('amount'=> 1)) obtengo object has no 'tax' property

Agradecería cualquier sugerencia. Saludos

Comment: El complex se llama `TaxesType`, y en el array tú le llamas `Taxes`, ¿no será por eso el error?

Comment: Muestra el codigo que has intentado haciendolo con clases

Comment: Agregué el código que hice con Clases. Se rompe de igual forma. Agradecería ayuda.

Comment: ¿Probaste usando `TaxesType` en lugar de `Taxes`? Hay una incoherencia de nombres entre el XML y el código PHP.

Comment: Taxes es del tipo TaxesType, eso reza el documento. Pero el problema es en la parte anidada, es como que pierde. Si ves en las pruebas que hice con array asociativo no toma los elementos.

Answer (score 0):

prueba con esta estructura en tu array:

```
$params = [
    'token' =>  'eltoken',
    'sign'  =>  'sign',
    'paymentEntity' =>  1001,
    'form'  =>  [
        'formNumber'    =>  123456,
        'idPaymentType' =>  654,
        'Obligations'   =>  [
            [
                'Taxes'  => [
                    'TaxesType' =>  [
                        'tax'    => 6041,
                        'amount' => 602.0
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Eso debido a que veo que de Taxes viene TaxesType y luego tax y amount

Comment: Gracias, probé de esta manera pero sigo sin poder resolverlo.